# python: how to find a subset of one set that is closest to another

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, subset, distance

I have the following optimization problem that I can solve by "brute force" but am wondering if someone has already implemented a solver that I could use to do it faster and more elegantly.

I have two disjoint lists of integers. These are actually unique so I can say these are two sets. One is short with (`s`) about `S=90000` elements, the other is long (`l`) with about `L=2.5M` elements. What I need is to extract from `l` a subset `l2` of length exactly `S` so that overall the distance between elements of `s` and `l2` is the smallest over all subsets of `l` of length `S`. Pairwise distance between elements of `s` and `l` is simply the absolute value of their difference.

So if `s` and `l` were not disjoint and `l` were a superset of `s`, the resulting `l2` would simply be identical to `s`.

Since the arrays are long, doing a brute force approach by testing various subsets of `l` is not practical.

Is there an existing optimization library of some sort or some other package that I could use to solve this?

By the way, there might be different ways of measuring a distance between two sets, and I don't really care which one it is as long as it would give 0 for the above extreme superset example.

Comment: This feels vaguely similar to what the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) string search does. It's not the same, but there is a resonance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said these are lists, but is there any reason to not temporarily convert them to numpy arrays?  This can be straight forward (in case you don't know how to do the conversion):

```
s = np.array(s)
l = np.array(l)
```

From there, you can make use of the "searchsorted" function.  My test run took just under 1.5 s.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

# build numpy array
s = np.random.rand(90000)
l = np.random.rand(2.5E6)


# sort
s.sort()
l.sort()

# searchsorted finds where values in array2 should be inserted in array1 to 
# maintain the "sortedness" of a new list
# define index locations where "s" should be inserted in "l"
indices = np.searchsorted(l,s)

# build dummy list to store "s2"
# this is faster than repeatedly resizing an array
s2 = s*0


# using "indices" determine which adjacent value is the nearest match
# need to be careful here since we cannot look "below" the first index
# nor can we look "above" the last value

d1 = dt.datetime.now()
for r in np.arange(s.shape[0]):
    ix = indices[r]

    if indices[r]==0:
        s2[ix] = l[0]
    elif indices[r]==l.shape[0]:
        s2[ix] = l[r-1]
    else:
        tmp = l[ix:ix+2]
        s2[r] = tmp[ np.abs(s[r]-tmp)==np.min(np.abs(s[r]-tmp)) ]

print('Execution time: ',dt.datetime.now()-d1)
```

I have run a couple trials and it looks like this works, but confirm for yourself.  If this does not work there should not be too much effort for tuning it in.

---

## BEGIN EDIT

---

Change the for loop to:

```
for r in np.arange(s.shape[0]):
    ix = indices[r]

    if indices[r]==0:
        s2[ix] = l[0]
        l[0] = np.nan
    elif indices[r]==l.shape[0]:
        s2[ix] = l[r-1]
        l[r-1] = np.nan
    else:
        width = 0

        while width<min([10,r]) and np.isnan(l[ix-width:ix+2+width].mean()):
            width += 1

        tmp = l[ix-width:ix+2+width]
        s2[r] = tmp[ np.abs(s[r]-tmp)==np.nanmin(np.abs(s[r]-tmp)) ][0]
        l[l==s2[r]] = np.nan
```

This does two things: 
1. it removes the nearest neighbor within l from being considered in future iterations
2. it incrementally increases the search width within l to ensure that a nearest neighbor is found

Again, this will likely require tweaking to dial it in.

Comment: this is a very elegant and probably fast solution.

Comment: this produces a lot of repeated elements in `s2` whereas I need 1-to-1. I'll see if I can fix it. Thx

Comment: That is right.  I had not considered that.  This is due to two reasons: 1. two values from s may have the same nearest neighbor in l even though the difference between the s[ix] and l[ix2] may be different for these s values.  2. searchsorted may make multiple insertions between adjacent values in l2 (i.e. five values from s may get jammed between s[1] and s[2]).  I think this can be mitigated (if not obviated) by making the suggested changes above.  However, these changes significantly increase the execution time (around 3-4 minutes for me).  It depends on how fast you need it to be I guess.

Comment: The first algorithm is not a solution to the asked problem as the resulting set is not a subset of l. Second solution looks a heuristic -- it surely will return a subset of l, but how do you prove or convince someone that it is indeed optimal?

Comment: Praveen -- you are correct that the first solution is not a proper solution to the question as the OP pointed out.  "optimization" is in the eye of the beholder as we typically stop optimizing due to diminishing returns.  As the question sits, the OP has not provided enough information to provide a full/final solution, hence I just tried to point the OP in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0):

The distance function could be critical. If you define the distance function as the absolute difference between the sum of elements in sets s and l2, then the problem is actually NP-hard. Essentially, you are trying to find a subset of set l whose sum is close to the sum of elements in s. And the subset-sum problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) can be mapped to this; which means there is no polynomial time algorithm to solve this. However, you can probably modify the pseudo-polynomial time solution for the subset-sum problem for your case too.